# Windows 10 update simply reboot the machine

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm tring to update many PC from Win7 to Win10, after the download it asked me for upgrading. After the reboot win 7 startend and that's all... looking into windows update I only found the win10 update as failed with code 8007139f.

I also tried to open the firewall to override the network proxy, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to update 1 PC via MediaCreationTool https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10. if it doesn't work, it could be that your Proxy doesn't want you to install this Windows Update. Do you get the Windows Update from a WSUS?

Comment: No, it is downloaded directly and not by WSUS. Can I use the same media-creation for many pc or everyone needs its own media?

Comment: WSUS would be perfect, because it would download windows 10 and just push its files to your computers, so they wouldn't have to connect to WinUpdate on their own. With the MediaCreationTool you can update to windows 10 on one PC, or create a windows 10 ISO for further use. you could mount the ISO with daemon tools on the PCs you want to update, start it and choose the upgrade option. if you create an ISO, the PCs don't need to connect to Windows Update anymore.

Comment: Are these systems compatible with Windows 10? Did you check the requirements? 
- You have to disable any antivirus/internet security tool (Disable or uninstall), cleanup the pc and try again. You must use a valid admin account. If you suspect there is a dcom configuration issue, try using dcomcnfg and Component Services folder > Double click on Computers folder > Right click on My Computer and then choose Properties. Analyze Com Security (Edit Defaults to see if yyour account is listed).

Comment: The strange thing is that I expect a reboot with the windows 10 update process, in these cases I have simply a reboot to the old o.s. I'm making the media with mediatool, i will see if this works.

Comment: @Ramhound I found the "Windows 10 update" as failed.

Comment: WindowsUpdate.log will contain other information you should provide.  This error seems directly linked configurations that use a [proxy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53722740-1a18-497e-9733-3b427d3017d6/windows-update-behind-a-proxy-error-8007139f?forum=w7itproinstall) which are unable to commucate with a require Microsoft domain.  If you are using a proxy, and you don't have the capability to adjust the proxy configuration yourself, have somebody do it for you.  If you are on a corprate domain that means you should contact your network Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues attempting to update to Win10 in place.  If you would like to keep your apps, users, and data, then make a bootable Win 10 DVD or USB.  Then, restart into Windows, close anything that starts automatically, and run the disk setup.  Use the "download updates" option so that it grabs all of your drivers ahead of time.  After a while, it will reboot, and hopefully, install without error.  This takes a HUGE amount of disk space.

Comment: The number of spelling mistakes makes this answer not very helpful, it also, does not explain in detail how to solve the author's problem.